# Can $u_n$ be a linear combination of the vectors in infinite set $S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

Suppose $u_n = a_1u_1 + a_2u_2$ for vectors $u$ in infinite set $S$. Even though it would seem to be, can $u_n$ be said to be a linear combination of the vectors in $S$? Because presumably that would mean to say 
$$u_n = a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + 0u_3 + ...$$
But my textbook defines a vector $u_n$ to be a linear combination of the vectors in $S$ if there exists a **finite** number of vectors and scalars such that you have equality. But here, technically, you do not have a finite number of vectors and scalars.

Comment: This is the main idea for Fourier Series ;)

Comment: What do you mean with "technically you do not have a finite number of vectors and scalars"? Here such finite number definitely exists and equals $2$.

Comment: What book are you using?  What is the *precise* definition of *linear combination* which is given in that book?

Comment: Damn, I see. I confused the condition "there exists a finite amount of vectors and scalars in $S$ such that equality holds" to mean there must be a finite amount of vectors in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find many examples of such linearly independent vectors.

For example, $$1,x,x^2, x^3,....$$

$$ \sin x, \sin 2x, \sin 3x, ......$$

Orthogonal polynomials are also good examples of linearly independent sets.

Comment: As I read the question, it is not about the existence of infinite linearly independent sets, but about what constitutes a "linear combination."  I *think* that the asker is confused about what it means to be a linear combination of vectors from an infinite set when a linear combination is, by definition, the sum of only a finite number of vectors.  I don't think that this answers the question, though I think that the asker *really* needs to clarify their question, too.